# Http post request by passing query params in angular 8

Tags: angular

How to send requested parameters as a query params.

I tried like

```
addLocal(data: any) {
   const queryParams = `?email=${data.email}&name=${data.name}&phone_number=${data.phone_number}`;
   return this.httpclient.post('https://www.example.com/coming/receive' + queryParams);
}
```

But with this getting error accepted arguments 2-3.

How to call such requests

With json i used like below, but for passing data as query?

```
addLocal(data: any) {
    return this.httpclient.post('https://www.example.com/coming/receive', data);
}
```

Comment: Read the docs: https://angular.io/guide/http#configuring-http-url-parameters. The docs also tell you a POST expects `(url, body[, options])`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using like this,

```
 return this.httpclient.post('https://www.example.com/coming/receive' + queryParams,{});
```

EDIT:

[**`Http POST`**](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#post) takes resource URL as a parameter and additional two paramters

- Data to POST in the body of the request
- Method HttpOptions (if any and is optional ex. header information).

Comment: I shouldn't have to say this to someone with 164krep, but it's helpful to explain what you've changed and *why*.

Comment: That link is not to the docs about POST, it's the one I posted above about query params. The options isn't just headers. And in a way we're all still learning, but at a certain rep you shouldn't still be learning *this*.

Comment: updated with correct link. Learning means not the answer here, the way i post answers and how i need to improve etc